Contar SI en App Script. ¿Cómo puedo contar los elementos de una lista (de texto) y me arroje un número en App Script?
Estoy recibiendo de un formulario de mi sitio web, datos que voy almacenando en una hoja de cálculo de Google.
Sin embargo, deseo contar el número de veces que aparece el RFC (elemento de texto) más de una vez (Ya que si hay más de 1, no se insertarán los datos puesto que ya existe el registro).
Esta es la parte de código que tengo, sé que devuelve un string y yo lo comparo con un número, pero es justo lo que no sé hacer. Conocer el número de veces que aparece un texto en la columna 5.
function contarSi() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheets();
  const data = sheet[0].getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for (var i =0; i < data.length; i++){
    var column5 = data[i][4];

    if (column5 >= 2){
      console.log(column5)
    }
  }
}


Hola. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué es lo que quieres contar exactamente? Pulsa en [edit] y clarifica tu problema.

RFC (elemento de texto) puede haber más elementos en una misma celda
getCounterText('Sheet1!E:E', 'RFC') función cuenta el número de coicidentes, incluye repedidos en la misma celda.(Búsqueda global)
/**
 * Count the number of times a text is matched
 * @param   {stringRange} range Get values.Example "Sheet1!B:B"
 * @param   {string}    textSarch Text to search.Example "Google". 
 * @returns {integer}   Number of matches
 */
function getCounterText(range, textSearch){
  /**Counter text*/
  let countText = 0;
  /**Global search text*/
  let getMactch;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName(range).getValues()
          .forEach(function(row){return row.forEach(function(column){ 
            getMactch = column.toString().match(textSearch);
            if(getMactch !== null){
              countText = countText + getMactch.input.split(' ').length;}})});
  console.log('Numero Elementos de', textSearch, 'total:', countText);
return countText;}  /*  End function  */

